# Is "what a pity" used as often as "what a shame"?

Tags: word-usage

As an ESL speaker, I'm puzzled by these two phrases...
Is "what a pity" used as often as "what a shame" in an English-speaking country?
Is there any difference between them in meaning or usage?

Comment: It seems they are converging: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+a+pity%2C+what+a+shame&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: It frequency only but not necessarily in meaning. For example, [*boy* and *girl* trend closely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boy%2Cgirl&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgirl%3B%2Cc0) but are opposite. In this example, it's curious to see that *girl* started trending more frequent than *boy* in about 1970.

Answer (score 4):

For the most part, they are the same, but there are some slight differences.

*What a pity* expresses sorrow. It is harsher than saying "I feel sorry for you," but it still shows sympathy. If a boy gets in a fight at school, his father might say "What a pity" to mean that he wishes the boy had not gotten in the fight in the first place, but he is still sorry for his son.

> **pity:** a feeling of sorrow and sympathy caused by the suffering of others: *what a pity we can't be with friends.* (Oxford Dictionary)

*What a shame* is a little colder. People use it to express a loss of respect for whatever they are talking about. For instance, if the boy is the one who started the fight, his father might say "What a shame." This means he has lost some respect for his son.

> **shame:** loss of respect; dishonour: *the incident had brought shame on his family.* (Oxford Dictionary)

Nowadays, I hear "what a shame" more often because it only has three syllables instead of four. Instead of "what a pity," I usually hear "that's too bad" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks so much! So in the degree of sounding harsh, it's "what a shame" > "what a pity" or "that's too bad"> "I feel sorry for you"?

Comment: Other than the definitions, the rest of your answer seems very opinion-based and does not reconcile with how I hear and use the two expressions.  Can you provide a citation or example for your statement "what a shame" is used more because it has one less syllable?